# Why is the title of a target questions in comments only shown in the title hover?

Tags: feature-request, comments, hyperlinks, title

If I post a link to a Question in a comment, why is it only shown in the Title and not as visible link?

For example in Questions If I post this URL:

[Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

It is replaced with the title, but in comments it stays as link and only if you hover over it with the mouse, you see the link.

It seems like the comment only parses the part in the url that represents the question title, because in the hover, the Capitilisation is lost (see example link).

If that javascript already gets the Question out of the link, why not directly display it as text?

Comment: Here, how it looks like in a comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage

Comment: If you post just the beginning of the URL there is no hover title: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892

Answer (score 2):

Because the link is too long to be fully displayed in a comment, you only see the title in the tooltip. If you don't want this, then use Markdown to display the title:

```
[Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)
```

See the result of this in my comment to this answer.

Or you can use the [SE Comment Link Helper](https://stackapps.com/q/2378/25384) userscript to automatically change the links into `[title](link)` format.

Comment: [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Comment: That is quite a lot work, cause you need to copy both, the url and the Question separately

Comment: @rubo77: Unless the SE team implements a feature that changes the link into text, this is the only way to do so. It's not that much work.

Comment: @rubo77: I found a userscript like that, I'll link it in my answer.

Comment: I installed it in Greasemonkey, but no change to the linnks in comments ;(

Comment: @rubo77: Works fine for me. Try it out here: paste a link in a comment and press "Add Comment". The comment will contain a link in the `[title](link)` format.

Comment: Ah I understand, it changes the link before the comment is posted, so exixting comments are not replaced

Comment: @rubo77: Apparently, it worked. Yes, it does not replace existing comments, because the userscript is created to avoid copying both the title and the link.

Comment: That could be changed: https://github.com/rchern/StackExchangeScripts/issues/68